# Wasserstein penalization for time dependent measures

Tags: optimal-transport

I have time dependant measures, say $\mu: [0,T]  \rightarrow \mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ and I'm looking to define a penalization in this space that would measure the amount of displacement in space through time.

My first option is to consider the Wasserstein metric. The simplest example I can think of is that for two time measurements $0\leq t_1<t_2 \leq T$, the following penalization can be considered
$$ P_2(\mu) = W_2(\mu(t_1), \mu(t_2))$$

More generally, I could consider for $0 = t_0 < \ldots < t_n = T$ 
$$ P_n(\mu) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} W_2(\mu(t_i), \mu(t_{i+1}))$$

So my question is, what happens when the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P_n(\mu)$ is considered? Does it has any name I could search in the literature?

Comment: You have to specify how you choose your partition to make this limit well-defined. Presumably you want that the mesh of the partition goes to zero, right? In this case, $n P_n(\mu)$ converges to the length of $\mu$ in the Wasserstein space. Thus $P_n(\mu)$ converges to zero if $\mu$ has finite length.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't noticed that the closet the times are, the closer is it's wasserstein distance (It's obvious now). 

So indeed this converges to the arclength using the Wasserstein distance. Has this being studied somewhere?